# iOS reading CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, reachability

I'm working on a iOS app which accesses jSON data, downloads it and stores it on Core Data while also displaying it over a Table View.

I'm trying to implement a method to load up the Core Data whenever the app is offline yet it doesn't seem to recognize the fact.

I believe the trouble lies in here:

```
-(BOOL)is_conected{
        Reachability *rc= [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
        NetworkStatus ns=[rc currentReachabilityStatus];

        if (ns != NotReachable) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /*****LOAD*****/
-(void)loadProduct{
        if([self is_conected]){
            [self downloadProduct];
        }
        else{
            [self readingCoreData];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
```

I'm convinced that the "else" in "loadProduct" doesn't get triggered and thus the method "readingCoreData" isn't executed.

I'd thought of using an "else if" condition but I'm not sure what I can use as a condition because it works with the output of the "is_connected" method above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you care if the app is offline to load up Core Data? If you're reading from JSON to store in Core Data, you should always be reading from Core Data. You can load from CoreData while you're downloading info, then once you get the info you can reload the table. Otherwise you're making the user wait for a response (which can take awhile depending on your connectivity) for information he/she mostly has already on the phone.

Comment: This app is supposed to have an "offline mode" in which you load up the Core Data to print out the Table View.

Comment: Right, you can do that while it's online too. The only difference is that you might have an update from the server you can get. But you can still load CoreData and present things to show the user while you get the updates from the server. Otherwise you're making them wait needlessly if there aren't any updates to get.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your suggestions. I'll think about it.

Comment: You're 'convinced'? How so - did you put a breakpoint in there? If so, then your loadProduct method looks fine - check your reachabilityForInternetConnection method.

Comment: Just a side note - if the code is not evaluating the else at all it could also be a compiler cacheing bug with XCode that a clean/delete derived data will fix (where it doesn't realize you added the else statement).